# Radiobutton Validation in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This validation works, but the error message is shown next to the radiobutton moving the before the default label for the radiobutton. Is there a way of putting the error message align to the right instead?

Run the code to see what I mean.

Thanks for your assistance.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Form Validation Demo</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#form1").validate({
                    rules: {

                        accept: "required",// simple rule, converted to {required:true}

                    },
                    messages: {

                         accept: "* Required",
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        label.error {  
            color: red;
         }
    </style>

    </head> 

    <body>
        <form id="form1" method="post" action="">
             <div>
            <input type="radio" name="accept" value="accept" /> Accept
             </div>
          <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>

     </BODY>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
label.error {  
    color: red;
    position:absolute;
    left:75px;
}
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/Ja8jr/

Comment: Thanks for that. I knew I was missing something :)